# DEBUG : MP3Player.h error loading a new music path : abort()

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, assert

I'm using a library which is called MP3Player.h and can be found [here](http://code4k.blogspot.fr/2010/05/playing-mp3-in-c-using-plain-windows.html). I use it for  helping me writing my own MP3 player in windows with c++ .

Everything is fine until today, i have progress and when i'm debugging an error abort() pop up .

screenies :

- [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmE3G.png)

The error reffer to a function called in MP3Player.h :

```
    // Sequence of call to get the MediaType
    // WAVEFORMATEX for mp3 can then be extract from MediaType
    mp3Assert(wmSyncReader->QueryInterface(&wmProfile));
    mp3Assert(wmProfile->GetStream(0, &wmStreamConfig));
    mp3Assert(wmStreamConfig->QueryInterface(&wmMediaProperties));

    // Retrieve sizeof MediaType
    mp3Assert(wmMediaProperties->GetMediaType(NULL, &sizeMediaType));

    // Retrieve MediaType
    WM_MEDIA_TYPE* mediaType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeMediaType);
    mp3Assert(wmMediaProperties->GetMediaType(mediaType, &sizeMediaType));

    // Check that MediaType is audio
    assert(mediaType->majortype == WMMEDIATYPE_Audio);
    // assert(mediaType->pbFormat == WMFORMAT_WaveFormatEx);

    // Check that input is mp3
    WAVEFORMATEX* inputFormat = (WAVEFORMATEX*)mediaType->pbFormat;
    assert(inputFormat->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_MPEGLAYER3);
    assert(inputFormat->nSamplesPerSec == 44100);
    assert(inputFormat->nChannels == 2);   // CRASHING HERE

    // Release COM interface
    // wmSyncReader->Close();
    wmMediaProperties->Release();
    wmStreamConfig->Release();
    wmProfile->Release();
    wmHeaderInfo->Release();
    wmSyncReader->Release();

    // Free allocated mem
    LocalFree(mediaType);
```

And there is the code i'm using in my main :

```
int main(void){
MP3Player player;
DIR* rep = NULL;


int timeRead = 0;
const size_t concatenated_size = 512;
char concatenated[concatenated_size];
double time;


struct dirent* fichierLu = NULL; 
rep = opendir("C:/Users/paul/Music/Playlisty");
if (rep == NULL)
    exit(1);

while ((fichierLu = readdir(rep)) != NULL) {


    printf("Le fichier lu s'appelle '%s'\n", fichierLu->d_name);


        // Open the mp3 from a file...

        timeRead++;
        if (timeRead > 79) { 


            printf("DEBUG : ");
            printf(fichierLu->d_name);
            printf("\n");

            concatenated[0] = '\0'; // set char array content to null
            time = 0;
            snprintf(concatenated, concatenated_size, "C:/Users/paul/Music/Playlisty/%s", fichierLu->d_name);   // load music path name into char array
            player.OpenFromFile(concatenated);  // load music from path

            player.Play();


            time = player.GetDuration(); // get time music
            Sleep(time * 1000); // wait music time : Time(s) * 1000 = milli
            player.Close(); // Close the player with current music
        }


}



if (closedir(rep) == -1)
    exit(-1);

system("Pause");
return 0;}
```

Thanks for reading my code , do you think the error come from my bad coding skill in the main or from the header MP3Player.h and how can i fix it ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: It looks like the debug assertion happens when the decoded file is not stereo.  Could you check the "Death.mp3" file with another audio app and find out if it is Mono or if there is something else odd about it?

Comment: I have tried with a lot of user music in my playlist but i have still the same result . The first music playing is just working fine but just when the music finish and start playing an other one the debug assertion start . I have updated my main code , but it's still not working . [link](http://pastebin.com/9dTh5Yaz)